# MVC routing is not handling one of my directories

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, http-status-code-403

I'm using ASP.NET MVC with IIS 7.0.  I've got 404 errors hooked up fine through my Application_Error override.

In addition to "Controllers", "Models", "Helpers" etc. I have a directory called 'Files' that I use to store user-uploaded files.  When I go to http://www.mysite.com/files, instead of getting a 'Not Found' I get a default IIS 403 page that gives way too much information (e.g. exact directory structure of the server):

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden
The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.
```

If I try to access http://www.mysite.com/controllers or http://www.mysite.com/helpers, which are both existing directories with code files, I get a 404 page, which is what I want.  I don't want the user to know anything about my directory structure.

Why is MVC not handling the /files directory?

Comment: Just out of interest, what is the purpose of these files? Are they being served up again? If so, how? Because my suggestion would be to store them outside of the web root so that the issue you have wouldn't be an issue.

Comment: That may be a better solution.  I haven't experimented with making the web root directory different from the server root.  It would probably be a good solution in this case.  These are just user-uploaded files that should not be directly accessible (only accessible through Actions in our MVC app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this one out.  The reason the Views directory was returning a proper '404' page but the Files directory was returning a too-much-information ASP.NET 'no permissions' page: there is a web.config file in the Views directory that prohibits showing files.  It has the snippets below to stop MVC from serving the directory.

I just added a similar web.config file to my Files directory, and MVC now acts like the directory doesn't exist, which is exactly what I want.

```
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="*" verb="*"
          type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </httpHandlers>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="BlockViewHandler"/>
      <add name="BlockViewHandler" path="*" verb="*" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.HttpNotFoundHandler"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: I second Charlino's comment on your original question. If these files should never be served as a direct response to an HTTP request then it's safer to just store them outside the web root. I usually have a folder structure like "app\web\" for the web site and "app\web_data\" for files like this.